# TStringGrid OnHeaderClick event

Tags: android, delphi

I have a simple Android application consisting of TSringGrid and 2 columns, one of which is TColumn and the other TCheckColumn.  I can sort on each of the columns using TButton and appropriate code, but the TButtons take up valuable screen space that could be better used. Is it possible to determine which column is selected by using the OnHeaderClick event and calling the appropriate action from that event.

Many Thanks ...

Comment: You receive a `TColumn` object passed to the `OnHeaderClick` event as parameter. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: I am sure you are correct Victoria, but I am unsure how to access the TColumn object information from the OnHeaderClick event.

Comment: It's passed as the `Column` parameter to that event, so access it through it ;-)

Comment: Hi again - I seem to be missing something very fundamental here - my problem is how to access from the OnHeaderClick, which column has been selected - I have searched high and low for example code  to no avail - I will search again ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, example of the event handler signature:

```
procedure TForm5.StringGrid1HeaderClick(Column: TColumn);
```

the `Column` parameter is the column whos header was clicked

There are many ways to detect which column was clicked, here are three:

Alternative one: check the `Header` property of the column

```
  if Column.Header = 'First column' then
    ShowMessage('First clicked')
  else
  if Column.Header = 'Second column' then
    ShowMessage('Second clicked');
```

Alternative two: check the `Name` property of the column

```
  if Column.Name = 'Column1' then
    ShowMessage('First clicked')
  else
  if Column.Name = 'CheckColumn1' then
    ShowMessage('Second clicked');
```

Alternative three: Assign values to the Tag property of each column
 at design time, and check Column.Tag value at runtime

```
  case Column.Tag of
    0: ShowMessage('First clicked');
    1: ShowMessage('Second clicked');
  end;
```

Of course you need to change the identifiers according to your actual grid.